# RDP session on W2022 Server Azure Edition has additional file share but SSH into same machine, same account does not

Tags: windows, powershell, ssh, windows-server-2022

From OS X, I can launch RDP and login to a Windows 2022 Server Azure Edition instance with name+password.  I have created a new drive `Z:` mapped to a storage file share using the `New-PSDrive` command from `powershell`.  I can stop and start the instance and I always get the `Z:` drive back.  Indeed, from OS X itself I can issue

```
open smb://myStorageAccount:<account_key>@myStorageAcccount.file.core.windows.net/myShareName
```

and it mounts the file share on `/Volumes/xfer` with POSIX compliance so my OS X and Windows directory view is the same; *very* handy.

I tried to add SSH in hopes of being able to do something like:

```
ssh -i keyfile.pem remoteUser@remoteIP powershell set-of-commands
```

I opened port 22 on the instance network security group and installed OpenSSH Server.  I can `ssh` into the machine using name+password.  I'd like to login with `ssh -i keyfile.pem` so I put my public key into `C:\Users\remoteUser\.ssh\authorized_keys` but `-i` option still prompts for password.   Let's consider this problem #2 to solve.

Problem #1 is after `ssh` login, I start a `powershell` and the 'Z:' drive is not there.  **Are drive mappings scoped only to the RDP instance?**   I am used to OS X / Linux where a filesystem mount is available (subject to permissions) to all.

I set up the `Z:` using the very helpful script on the file share create page that looks like this:

```
$connectTestResult = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName test1diag427.file.core.windows.net -Port 445
if ($connectTestResult.TcpTestSucceeded) {
    # Save the password so the drive will persist on reboot
    cmd.exe /C "cmdkey /add:`"myStorageAccount.file.core.windows.net`" /user:`"localhost\mySTorageAccount`" /pass:`"<account_key>`""
    # Mount the drive
    New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\myStorageAccount.file.core.windows.net\myShareName" -Persist
} else {
    Write-Error -Message "Unable to reach the Azure storage account via port 445. Check to make sure your organization or ISP is not blocking port 445, or use Azure P2S VPN, Azure S2S VPN, or Express Route t\
o tunnel SMB traffic over a different port."
}
```

and this worked for the initial RDP session.  When I try:

```
New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\myStorageAccount.file.core.windows.net\myShareName" -Persist -Cred <account_key>
```

it just hangs.  In fact, I cannot even use `Ctrl+C` to break out; I have to wait 60 seconds or so then issue `~.` to get the local `ssh` client to break the connection.  And when I try the `cmd.exe /C "cmdkey /add` command before `New-PSDrive` without the `-Cred` option, I get this error:

```
CMDKEY: Credentials cannot be saved from this logon session.
```

So I am thinking I am fundamentally not understanding how login sessions and drive mappings work in Windows.

### EDIT

I added `-Scope Global` to the `New-PSDrive` command, dropped the drive with `Remove-PSDrive Z`, then made sure to dot-source the script.  No change in behavior.  RDP session sees `Z:` but other `ssh` session does not.

Any clues on problem #1 and #2 appreciated.

Comment: Powershell is using a different process so you are not logged in and do not see drive.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell?view=powershell-7.4